# DER para aluno, disciplina e curso

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, der

- Um estudante só pode ter um curso.
- Um curso tem várias disciplinas.
- O aluno pode cursar várias disciplinas do curso.

A minha única dúvida é como ficaria isso no DER?

[image: DER]

Ficaria realmente desse jeito?

Já que aluno só tem um curso, a *table* seria `disciplinaAlunoCurso`? Ou só `disciplinaAluno`?

Vai que o aluno mude de curso depois, então a melhor opção seria essa? Colocar as três chaves de cada tabela como estrangeira na tabela de ligação?

Comment: E se ele fizer 2 cursos? Se estiver resolvendo dependência? Acho mais interessante o aluno ter uma tabela de relacionamento com turmas de disciplinas. você cria as turmas, e adiciona uma entrada para aquele aluno naquela turma da disciplina.

Comment: Um exemplo pra ficar mais claro: Vamos supor que a disciplina "Neurologia II" tenha uma "turma noturna B do 1o semestre de 2015". Neste caso, o aluno está inscrito nesta turma especificamente, e não simplesmente em "Neurologia II". Semestre que vem, já vão ser outras turmas de Neurologia II, e se esse aluno ficar com dependência desta disciplina, vai ter que se inscrever nesta nova turma. O aluno se relaciona com a turma. A turma é que se relaciona com as disciplinas.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Vou dar uma resposta para lhe dar uma orientação. Se não é isso que precisa, complicou, porque não dá para ficarmos debatendo aqui até chegar aonde você quer, deixaria de ser uma pergunta e uma resposta.

Você não especificou bem o problema. Claro, quando especificar o modelo fica praticamente pronto. Mas sem especificar fica difícil lhe ajudar. Terei que especular. Principalmente porque você disse que não quer algo mais complexo. Para fazer tudo correto algo mais complexo é necessário. Mas se você aceita que não esteja tudo "correto", qual é o limite aceitável? Só você sabe.

De fato, esse correto é bem entre aspas porque é difícil dizer que tem certo ou errado em modelagem. O correto do ponto de vista acadêmica nem sempre é muito prático. Muitas vezes para otimizar o banco de dados é necessário fazer o "errado".

Quando você quer soluções simples que apenas funcione, fazer tudo como mandam os livros pode ser um exagero.

Mas só você sabe o ponto de inflexão.

Vou dar algumas dicas do que eu faria olhando por cima e fazendo algumas especulações.

## Considerações

O campo `cursoID` de `aluno` pode até ser usado, mas se quer fazer o certo deveria ter uma tabela que amarra o aluno ao curso. Pode ser exagero criar uma tabela só para isto, mas faz mais sentido (é o que eu falei que não dá para saber o limite). Um aluno não tem por característica um curso, curso é algo transitório, é algo externo e independente do aluno.

Para isto existe o relacionamento 1:1. Curiosamente as pessoas acham que se é 1:1 pode sempre ignorar a criação de uma tabela e juntar tudo. Mas se você achar que é exagero e cabe ficar na mesma tabela, posso concordar. Você é que decide. E quem pode falar que vai dar algum problema?

Eu imagino que o aluno pode ter zero ou um curso e não apenas um. Então é para se pensar. Claro que o `null` existe para casos como esse. Há muita controvérsia se deve ou não usar nulos para isto (eliminar um relacionamento).

Uma disciplina só existe para aquele curso? Parte da modelagem diz que sim, parte diz que não.

Não importa como vai relacionar, falta ligar a tabela `disciplina` com `curso` de alguma forma.

Se a disciplina só existe para aquele curso é uma relação 1:1, então você pode escolher se vai fazer uma tabela para fazer a amarração da disciplina ao curso ou vai usar um campo como você fez. Qual é o mais certo é difícil dizer. Uma disciplina pode ficar sem um curso?

Se a disciplina está vinculada a apenas um curso, se o aluno mudar de curso ele não está mais cursando aquela disciplina.

Mas se a disciplina pode existir em vários cursos tem duas coisas a considerar: precisa ter uma amarração entre cursos e disciplina; e então não importa (?!? depende) em que curso o aluno está cursando-a, ele cursa a disciplina.

E aí o campo `cursoId` de `disciplinaAlunoCurso` não seria necessário.

Você levantou essa possibilidade do aluno trocar de curso e ainda continuar cursando a disciplina, então a disciplina não pode simplesmente pertencer ao curso, mas sim vários cursos podem ter relacionamento com as disciplinas.

Depois você vai usar a informação disponível de todas as disciplinas que ele completou e todas necessárias para o curso para saber se ele concluiu o curso. Mas já estamos indo além da modelagem.

Já que se falou tanto em turmas nos comentários e é o correto considere criar uma tabela de turmas e relacionar o aluno e a disciplina à turma. Isto não resolve todas as situações possíveis em uma escola, mas já resolve uma importante. E aí obviamente a amarração será aluno X disciplina X turma. Eventualmente de curso também. Eu sou um exemplo vivo de que isso é necessário porque mudei de turno e tive que fazer diversas disciplinas do meu curso em turmas de outros cursos (o que às vezes descobri que a disciplina não era bem a mesma).

## Conclusão

Se for analisar tudo o que pode acontecer, pensar que uma mudança de cursos provavelmente precisa ser registrada adequadamente guardando histórico do que ele fez, que podem existir turmas diferentes, e que tem uma série de outros elementos e fatores envolvidos, vai ficar bem complexo. Se deixar tudo isto de lado em última análise pode ter uma tabela única que cuida de tudo.

Mas não garanto nada disso, pode ser que precise ser diferente. É mais fácil fazer modelagem de situações reais. Ou pelo menos de situações hipotéticas bem especificadas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso + o que o Bacco comentou sobre as turmas já devem dar uma bela ajuda ao usuário, +1.

Comment: Eu quase falei das turmas mas sei lá, pode ser um cursinho furreca que não tem nada disto :) Claro que idealmente teria porque ninguém se matricula em uma disciplina e sim em uma turma. A disciplina não fica inativa quando os alunos terminam ela. A turma sim. Mas é o que eu falei, para fazer certo, pensar em tudo, vai ficando complexo.

Comment: Exatamente, se deixar de associar a uma turma você perde não só o "nome" da turma, mas o ano e o semestre, que provavelmente serão necessários na hora de se associar uma nota ao aluno. Mas, como você já disse, cabe ao AP decidir se o modelo precisa ou não lidar com isso.

Comment: Eu quis não inventar muito além do que ele já definiu mas certamente é algo interessante a adicionar. Eu faria assim. Alias já fiz para uma escola em um dos meus primeiros sistemas quando tinha 17 anos :) Inicialmente em dBase :P e depois Clipper. Boas memórias. Pena não ter mais os fontes para recordar.

Comment: Excelente explicação, estou passando por um problema parecido, ainda estou precisando entender a logica por trás, para modelar o banco de dados e fazer as ligações certas.